# How can I get the component code before compile in Vue2.x?

Tags: vue.js

#### What problem does this feature solve?

```
<code-box title="基本" describe="button基本用法">
    <i-button>Default</i-button>
</code-box>
```

- I want to get default Slot String like **`<i-button>Default</i-button>`** in codeBox.
- I can find then api **_slotContents** in vue 1.x.
- Is there any way can get the same function in vue 2.x?

#### What does the proposed API look like?

_slotContents in vue 1.x

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Vue templates are compiled into JavaScript code and the original template string is not remembered. Why do you need it anyway? Maybe there's a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to use [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots).

If for some reason you really want to get the rendered html inside your component you can use `this.$el.innerHtml`.

Comment: `this.$el.innerHtml` will return the result  compile;
`<i-button>Default</i-button>` maybe renderd like '<button class="i-btn">Default</button>'